# What does the XOR mathematically do?

Tags: math, bit-shift, xor

So I understood what the XOR does and how it works, but I didn't get what it mathematically does, how it works directly on the numbers, like isn't there a mathematical operation for it ?

Comment: Addition modulo 2 on each bit?

Comment: You can also think of it as a [half adder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adder_(electronics)#Half_adder) without the carry output.

Comment: You may want to look at [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1080223/147357).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about mathematics instead of directly about programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XOR is addition in GF(2<sup>k</sup>) where k is the number of bits you're working with. This interpretation is common in cryptography.

Comment: Thanks ! Will have to understand what the GF(2^k) is now. Anyway, thanks

Answer (score 1):

It does addition but without the carry.

You can do it on higher numbers other than {0,1} aswell:

For example with an alphabet of number: {0,1,2,3,4}

Adding 234 + 143 gives you 322

Edit:

[image: example of full adder]

If you look at this example diagram here and ignore the carry input (C) and carry output (Carry) and set them to 0 you are left with a simple XOR.